# VS2013 doesn't have windows driver template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, kmdf

My visual studio 2013 ultimate doesn't have "Windows Driver" template in New Projects.
I mean that I want to have something like following picture:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

How can i add this template to my visual studio? What packages should I install?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it say on the very page you linked `Visual Studio along with the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)`?

Comment: I'm having the same problem: missing templates. I DO have Visual Studio Pro along with WDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Windows WDK 8.1 I found that I had the missing templates I was looking for (drivers templates). So you'll need VS 2013, as well as WDK 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

And ... ditto.

Installed VS 2013 pro, then installed the WDK 8 and/or 8.1 - no templates.
Control Panel, Change-> Repair -- no templates.
Reinstalled. Ditto.

Lots of Internet complaints, suggesting a "registration" problem with the install. Only positive outcome from those posts was 1 dude who *reinstalled his whole OS* just to get the VS and WDK working with a kmdf template option.